# How to ı use function for the only localstorage events, without component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I must add localstorage events for my project but ı wanna this function doesn't include other functions for code pollution. How can ı apply this function?
My current code such;

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";

function LocalStorageEvents() {
  useEffect(() => {
    JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("countries"));
  }, []);
  return null;
}

LocalStorageEvents();
```

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to achieve here . can you be more specific ? . Are you trying to set a value to local storage or you want to read the value from local storage and use it in your component ?

Comment: Okay, I wanna this function is running, but not render anything. Only for localstorage events. For now, this function is not running because it's no render anything.

Comment: For example when ı write "console.log("Hello World")" this not showing in the console.

Comment: then in that case all you need is a util function . like setLocalStorage(key, value) and getLocalStorage(key)

Comment: Simply use pure javascript function set and get implement in separate js file and export it

Comment: @RaviGajera In this case, ı can't use "useEffect" function of React.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks outside of React. If you want to run this function only once you can use `useEffect` inside your App.js:

```
function App() {
   useEffect(() => console.log(localStorage.getItem("countries")), [])
   // rest of your render method goes here
}
```

By doing so, you can ensure that localStorage is fetched only once unless App.js is somehow remounted, which I wouldn't expect.

The second choice is to convert your function into a regular javascript function. You can call it in any file such as index.js and it should work.

```
function fetchCountries() {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("countries")));
}

fetchCountries();
```

Comment: Thanks, Onur, I wanna this function doesn't include in the App.js. How can ı provide this?